# can not access url path in production environment in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, url-routing, server-side-rendering

I have deployed my website on production but the issue i'm facing is my all routes working fine Locally but not on production. e.g when i enter website url like [www.xyz.com/Login](http://www.xyz.com/Login), it should redirect to login page but it remains on home page(/) or [www.xyz.com/](http://www.xyz.com/) . And when i do the same thing on localhost it's working fine even i can access any page in my website, whereas when i deploy it on production it doesn't work. As well I have a menu bar which contains all pages links when i click on any page it redirects me to that page but when i manually copy that link and paste in another tab it remains on home (/) page.

UPDATE: I have build my project using npm build and export commands and uploaded it on s3 bucket.

Comment: The info you provide is not enough. Several parameters may be responsible here. For example what server is your production running at? There may be a server in front of your app thus the configuration there be different than your local server running on plain npm

Comment: @nikos.svnk Thanks!  My production server is running on AWS and i'm updating the module.config.js file. so will have better idea.

Comment: @nikos.svnk I have updated the question please acknowledge.